# Responsive table with single column

Tags: css, html-table

I am trying to work out a solution with 3 defined responsive layouts using css to display output from a database for different size devices.

For desktop a normal table works fine in the form:

| Title Column 1 | Title Column 2 | Title Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data Column 1 Row 1 | Data Column 2 Row 1 | Data Column 3 Row 1 |
| Data Column 1 Row 2 | Data Column 2 Row 2 | Data Column 3 Row 2 |
| Data Column 1 Row 3 | Data Column 2 Row 3 | Data Column 3 Row 3 |

For Tablet size screen table is formatted with 2 columns:

| Title Column 1 | Data Column 1 Row 1 |
| --- | --- |
| Title Column 2 | Data Column 2 Row 1 |
| Title Column 3 | Data Column 3 Row 1 |
| Title Column 1 | Data Column 1 Row 2 |
| Title Column 2 | Data Column 2 Row 2 |
| Title Column 3 | Data Column 3 Row 2 |
| Title Column 1 | Data Column 1 Row 3 |
| Title Column 2 | Data Column 2 Row 3 |
| Title Column 3 | Data Column 3 Row 3 |

For a phone screen I only want one column as shown below:
| Title Column 1
|:---:|
| Data Column 1 Row 1
|Title Column 2
|Data Column 2 Row 1
|Title Column 3
|Data Column 3 Row 1
|Title Column 1
|Data Column 1 Row 2
|Title Column 2
|Data Column 2 Row 2
|Title Column 3
|Data Column 3 Row 2
|Title Column 1
|Data Column 1 Row 3
|Title Column 2
|Data Column 2 Row 3
|Title Column 3
|Data Column 3 Row 3

Is there any CSS wizardry to achieve this? The reason I want to do this is because the 2nd column can have a lot more data so 2 columns on a phone screen will not format well.

Any insightful tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tables aren’t really meant to work that way. Can you use Grid?